# Remove specific word from a dfm

Tags: r, quanteda

From this process

```
    library(stm)
library(tidyr)
library(quanteda)
     testDfm <- gadarian$open.ended.response %>%
             tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
             dfm()
```

Let's say that we check the frq

```
dftextstat <- textstat_frequency(testDfm)
```

and we want to remove some specific words from dfm. Accroding to the dftextstat we want to remove `c("and", "to")` Is there any way to make it in the dfm without the need to run again the lines to create the dfm?

Comment: Can you make a reprodcuible example

Comment: @akrun yes please se the updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a dfm, you can use `dfm_remove` to remove features.

Based on your example:

```
# remove "and" and "to"
testDfm <- dfm_remove(testDfm, c("and", "to"))
```

Better to remove all the stopwords with:

```
dfm_remove(testDfm, stopwords("english"))
```

If you still have a tokens object, you can use `tokens_remove` in the same manner, or in the pipeline you have like above.